# Use xslt + xml ==>html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Use xslt to defines template, xml to save data. And transfer to html in client. Is this okay?

I am not know well about xslt, and just write a simple demo, feel not bad.

If I use xslt in website practically, what problem would I meet during coding?

Is there some famous website use xslt?

or say something about xslt...thanks.

Comment: I'll say something about xslt ... it's totally cool stuff :)

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to try something and post another question if you're stuck. Some background would help too, surely you must have some reason to even suggest using these technologies.

Comment: @Jack: yeah..I just collect suggestions because some people against using these (even the demo seems good.) [by the way: maybe I mis understand your words.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES**.  XSLT is exactly that.  You may want to render it server-side so you can get some caching and avoid some odd browser quirks, but XML + XSLT is the "first best answer" for web development, and any other technology stack needs to prove itself a better alternative.

The big issue if you just send XML + XSLT down the wire is parser differences.  Chrome and FireFox use entirely different rendering engines than IE, and that shows up especially with XSLT.  Not to mention that Microsoft's MSXML parser (which is in IE, windows, and System.XML) simply does not support any of the nifty things in XSLT 2.0

The only real downside to just serving XML+XSLT, and the likely reason most websites don't, is that you either lose the ability to progressively enhance your design or you need to jump through additional hoops to do so.  It's great for highly regular sites that don't have a lot of moving parts or scripted client-side interactivity, but there is a trade off.